# Update between 2 datatables using linq/lambda

Tags: linq, lambda, replace, datatable, compare

CtExcelData [datatable1]

```
DESIGNATION                        STATUS
------------------------------------------
ASSISTANT MANAGER - TRAINING       ACTIVE
ASSISTANT MANAGER - TRAINING       ACTIVE
ADMIN ASSISTANT                    ACTIVE
```

Designation [datatable2]

```
DESIG_ID    DESIG_NAME
------------------------------------------
10          ASSISTANT MANAGER - TRAINING
20          ADMIN ASSISTANT
```

I want to replace datatable1 `DESIGNATION` text with designation id in datatable2 if designation name exactly matches between 2 datatables using lambda expression.

There will be multiple rows in 2 tables.

Comment: Lambda expressions don't modify objects. There's a lot of information missing in this question, esp. details about the data layer(s) you're using. It would be most clarifying if you could show some first efforts, however tentative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//CtExcelData datatable imported from excel compared with Designation datatable fetched from db. Updated excel datatable with id from db table matching the designationname

foreach (DataRow row in CtExcelData.Rows){
DataRow desigRowsToUpdate = DS.Tables["Designation"].AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("Desig_Name").ToUpper().Trim() == row.Field<string>("DESIGNATION").ToUpper().Trim());
if (desigRowsToUpdate != null)
{
    row.SetField("DESIGNATION", desigRowsToUpdate.Field<decimal>("Desig_Id"));}
}
```